# multiple FlinkKinesisProducer as sink for a datastream

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I have multi level KDA with Flink applications in different accounts. I have the use case where I need to look at record contents to determine what AWS account to push the data to (kinesis stream in that account).

[link](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kinesis/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kinesis/FlinkKinesisProducer.java#L284) shows its possible to select stream name based on record contents, I need to support multiple kinesis producers for pushing to diff AWS accounts.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use [Side Outputs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/side_output.html) to configure a dedicated sink (and therefore, `FlinkKinesisProducer`) for a different AWS account.

You can make it as follows:

```scala
val stream: DataStream[T] = ...
val account1OutputTag = OutputTag[T]("aws-account-1-output")
...
val accountNOutputTag = OutputTag[T]("aws-account-N-output")

val mainDataStream = stream
  .process(new ProcessFunction[T, T] {
    override def processElement(
        value: T,
        ctx: ProcessFunction[T, T]#Context,
        out: Collector[T]): Unit = {
      // emit data to regular output
      out.collect(value)

      // emit data to a corresponding side output
      ctx.output(accountKOutputTag, value)
    }
  })

...

val account1SideOutputStream: DataStream[T] = mainDataStream
    .getSideOutput(account1OutputTag)
    .addSink(account1KinesisProducer)
...

val accountNSideOutputStream: DataStream[T] = mainDataStream
    .getSideOutput(accountNOutputTag)
    .addSink(accountNKinesisProducer)
```